# Ansible dropping root privilege after long-running task

Tags: ansible

I'm writing an ansible playbook to setup my system. This includes installing applications (via the [`package` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/package_module.html) - some of which (e.g.`texlive-full`) take a long time to download and install.

The task looks like this:

```
- name: install packages
  package:
    name: '{{ item }}'
    state: present
  with_items: [firefox, gimp, inkscape, texlive-full, ..., steam]
  become: yes
```

I execute the playbook containing this task with `ansible-playbook playbook.yml -K`.

When the install process takes too long, ansible doesn't retain it's root privilege (escalated with `become`) and thus installation of the next application fails.

How can I make ansible keep the privilege?

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, you shouldn't run the `package` module in a loop, because this means you have to recalculate dependencies for each individual package. This results in a lot of extra work and thus longer execution times.

You should pass a list of packages as an argument to the `name` parameter, like this:

```
- name: install packages
  package:
    name: "{{ packages }}"
    state: present
  vars:
    packages:
      - firefox
      - gimp
      - inkscape
      - texlive-full
      ...
      - steam
  become: yes
```

This will install all the packages in a single step, which means regardless of how long it takes there's really no mechanism by which Ansible could somehow "lose" privileges.